# Yii2 virtual attribute getter had to change to function call

Tags: methods, yii2, getter-setter, virtual-attribute

I'm new to OOP and Yii2. I have a function in Model:

```
public function getDatRev() {
    if ($this->rev) {
        return $this->rev;
    } else {
        return $this->datum;
    }
}
```

in the `View` until now I have used it like this:

```
$model->datRev;
```

and it would return the correct value. Now I don't know what has changed, maybe I was also updated the framework, but the old construct doesn't work anymore, and in order to make it work I have to change it to:

```
$model->getDatRev();
```

Can you please explain to me why that is?

Answer (score 1):

When you try get property the Yii2 calls magic method `__get ()`. Return value is depend from implementation of this method in parent class. Yii2 can check if this property exist in some container, or if exist getter of this property.
In your case seems like you don't call parent's method `__get()`. This may have happened because you override `__get()` method or initialized this property.

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to extend `yii\base\Object` (directly or not) in order to use short property syntax (`$model->abc` instead of `$model->getAbc()`). Magic method `__get()` @Timur mentioned is defined there and further extended in `yii\base\Component` class.

Comment: I have generated my models with giiant and I definitely haven't changed such base things. If it was like this before (because it was working), than it's also like this now. Probably I have changed something, but I have no clue what could result something like this. This is crazy...